# Invalid CSRF TOKEN Node js multer

Tags: node.js

**I am trying to upload files below is my implementations, I am using multer, basically, this setup works when I perform normal form submission with a form action and all. I want to do it asynchronously**
am i doing something wrong ???

```
<form id="announcementPostForm" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" class="_csrf" id="_csrf" value="<%=csrfToken%>">
     <input id="attachment" type="file"/>
     <button class="btn btn-custom float-right mb-2 postAnnouncementBtn"> Post </button>
</form>

----Client JS ------
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('attachment',document.getElementById("attachment").files[0])
    fetch('/createAnnouncement',{
        method: 'POST',
        body:formData
    }).then(result => {
        return result.json();
    }).then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
```

**server returns  message: 'invalid csrf token',
code: 'EBADCSRFTOKEN'**

```html
//csrf - cross site scripting 
const csrf = require('csurf');

const app = express();

//store files
const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:(req, file, cb)=>{
      cb(null,'uploads/files')
    }, 
    filename:(req, file, cb)=>{
      cb(null, new Date().getTime().toString()+'-'+file.originalname)
    }
});

//filtering incoming attachments
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if(file.mimetype === 'application/pdf' || file.mimetype === 'text/plain' || file.mimetype ==='image/png' || file.mimetype ==='image/jpg'|| file.mimetype ==='image/jpeg'){
      cb(null, true);
    }else{
      cb(null, false);
    }
}

//multer middleware
app.use(
  multer({
    storage:fileStorage,
    fileFilter:fileFilter,
  }).single('attachment')
);

app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'uploads')));

const csrfProtection = csrf();
app.use(csrfProtection);
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.csrfToken = req.csrfToken();
    next();
  })
app.use(authRoutes);
```

Comment: add your NodeJS code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request you `fetch()` from your browser code to your server *is* a cross-site request forgery (csrf). You configured your server to reject those, and you configured your `announcementPostForm` in your HTML with the appropriate `value="<%=csrfToken%>">` token. So that one is not a forgery. But the one you `fetch()` is.

To prevent it from being a forgery, you need to include that same form field, named `_csrf`, in your `fetch` request. Your client Javascript code can retrieve that from your html form something like this, to include it in your `formData` object.

```
var formData = new FormData();
const csrf = document.querySelector('form#announcementPostForm #_csrf').value
formData.append('_csrf', csrf)
formData.append('attachment',document.getElementById("attachment").files[0])
...
```

And, by the way your html form field won't work as written. Each field to be sent to your server needs  a `name` attributes as well a an `id` attribute. And you must mark the button as having `type="submit"`.

```html
<form id="announcementPostForm" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" class="_csrf" id="_csrf" name="_csrf" value="<%=csrfToken%>">
     <input id="attachment" name="attachment" type="file"/>
     <button 
          class="btn btn-custom float-right mb-2 postAnnouncementBtn"
          type="submit"> Post </button>
</form>
```

You also must use sessions in your nodejs program, and mention `credentials: 'same_origin'` in the options to your `.fetch()` request.

What happens here?  Each time your page is rendered it gets a different, hard-to-guess, `res.locals.csrfToken` value. Then when you post back to the server, it checks the incoming `_csrf` value against your session. This prevents cybercreeps from scraping your html and posting rubbish or malicious data to your server.

Comment: i am using sessions

Comment: This Solution worked

formData.append('_csrf', csrf)

Thanks O. Jones